# Express this with an existential quantifier and universal quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone verify I'm doing this correctly?

English: 
No Humans live in the Ocean

H(x): x is a human
O(x): x lives in the ocean

```
(using universal quantifier)
∀x [H(x) -> ¬O(x)]

(using existential quantifier)
¬Ǝx [H(x) ^ ¬O(x)]
```

(sorry i forgot to include the other portion)

Answer (score 2):

No, when you negate an implication you get the conjunction of the antecedent and the negation of the consequent.  So $\lnot (p \implies q)$ gives $p \land \lnot q$

Comment: I forgot to include what it was I was trying to express. Does that make a difference?  or would the 2nd part be ¬Ǝx [H(x) ^ O(x)]

Comment: It doesn't assuming (as now looks correct) that the universal statement is correct.  Then the existential statement should be what you give in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that an equivalent form of $p\to q$ is $\neg p\lor q$. Thus, you have
$$
(\forall x)(H(x)\to\neg O(x)) \equiv (\forall x)(\neg H(x)\lor\neg O(x)). 
$$
Hence, when you negate this, it becomes
$$
\neg[(\forall x)(\neg H(x)\lor\neg O(x))]\equiv (\exists x)\neg[(\neg H(x)\lor\neg O(x))]\equiv (\exists x)(H(x)\land O(x)),
$$
where the last equivalence is reached by a simple application of DeMorgan's Law (i.e., $\neg(p\lor q)\equiv \neg p\land \neg q$).